# Heroku CI status badge

Tags: heroku, heroku-ci, heroku-pipelines

Im using Heroku CI to run tests in Heroku Pipeline. I would like to add CI status as badge in the README.md file at Github, for `master` branch.

But so far, I have not found out-of-box solution on this request. Any tip on workarounds to get this work without building the ci-badge solution myself?

**Few inspirations I have found**:

1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-ci: (see the status badge on top of README.md. However, image URL is specifically searching for pipelines for the Heroku CI application, and doesnt work with other applications)
2. https://github.com/pussinboots/heroku-badge: displays `deploy` badges, which is not important for me. Also, this repo/app doesn't seem to be maintained anymore (last commit 2 years ago)

Answer (score 11):

I agree that a good Heroku CI badge generator is lacking! Heroku is still running one [here](https://ci-badges.herokuapp.com/), but the linked GitHub repo is unfortunately 404 (and, as you noted, that generator doesn't seem to work with pipelines other than Heroku's own, which makes it not that useful).

In any and all cases, inspired by your question, I went ahead and created a Heroku CI badge app that you can deploy to your Heroku account! Please find it [here](https://github.com/gregsadetsky/heroku-ci-badge).

Feel free to open issues / fork it if you want to change anything.

Cheers

Comment: I've contacted Heroku support on the badges matter and that's what they replied: " I agree this would be nice to have. Unfortunately, the app, which the GitHub repo returns a 404 was from an internal Hackathon. The https://ci-badges.herokuapp.com/ should probably be offline. It requires access to one of our internal services which the API access token as expired so the app will not work." And they took down the ci-badges.herokuapp.com

Comment: Thanks, Maxim! Good for contacting them, and farewell to ci-badges.herokuapp.com -- we hardly knew ya ;-)